# C# HTTP GET request to http://sede.educacion.gob.es/

Tags: c#, get, request

I am trying to perform a GET request to https://sede.educacion.gob.es/publiventa/catalogo.action?cod=E; with the cod=E parameter, in the browser, the web site open a menu below "Materias de educación", but when I perform the request using C# this menu is not loading and I need it. This is the code I am using to readHtml as string to later parse it with HtmlAgilityPack.

```
private string readHtml(string urlAddress)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0";
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;

            if (response.CharacterSet == null)
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            }
            else
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
            }

            string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();

            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();
            return data;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: From the code provided the HTML markup is read correctly from the method. You may need to provide more detail regarding *menu is not loading*. The menu HTML is definitely in the response.

Comment: Did you get it to work? If not, I have a possible solution. Let me know.

Comment: @Nico in my question I mention a menu below "Materias de educación", when I perform the request from C# and I visualize the string with the html code of the page this menu is not showing. Thank you for trying to help

Comment: @Jimi I don't hava a solution yet, i would like you share with me that possible solution. Thank you

Comment: Sure. I'll write down what I could come up with. Nothing great, but it might let you work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Uri you posted (https://sede.educacion.gob.es/publiventa/catalogo.action?cod=E) uses a Javascript switch to show the Menu content.
When you connect to that Uri (without clicking a menu link), that site shows three different versions of that page.

1) Page with closed menu and proposed new editions
2) Page with closed menu and search engine fields
3) Page with open menu and a selection of the menu content

This switch is based on a internal procedure which records the current session. Unless you click on a menu link (which is connected to an event listener), the Javascript proc shows the page in different states.
I gave it a look; those script are quite long (a whole multi-purpose library) and I had no time to parse it all (may be you can do that) to find out what parameters the event listener is passing.

But, the three-state version switch is constant.
What I mean is you can call that page three times, preserving the Cookie Container: the third time you connect to it, it will stream the whole menu content and its links.

> If you request three times the same page, the third time the Html page will
>   contain all the
> `Materias de educación` links

```
public async void SomeMethodAsync()
{
    string HtmlPage = await GetHttpStream([URI]);
    HtmlPage = await GetHttpStream([URI]);
    HtmlPage = await GetHttpStream([URI]);
}
```

This is, more or less, what I used to get that page:

```
CookieContainer CookieJar = new CookieContainer();

public async Task<string> GetHttpStream(Uri HtmlPage)
{
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest;
    string Payload = string.Empty;
    httpRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(HtmlPage);

    try
    {
        httpRequest.CookieContainer = CookieJar;
        httpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        httpRequest.ConnectionGroupName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        httpRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        httpRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        httpRequest.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 30000;
        httpRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        httpRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0";
        httpRequest.Accept = "ext/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        httpRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
        httpRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate;q=0.8");
        httpRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache");


        using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)await httpRequest.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            Stream ResponseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();

            if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    //ResponseStream.Position = 0;
                    Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(httpResponse.CharacterSet);

                    using (MemoryStream _memStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        if (httpResponse.ContentEncoding.Contains("gzip"))
                        {
                            using (GZipStream _gzipStream = new GZipStream(ResponseStream, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress))
                            {
                                _gzipStream.CopyTo(_memStream);
                            };
                        }
                        else if (httpResponse.ContentEncoding.Contains("deflate"))
                        {
                            using (DeflateStream _deflStream = new DeflateStream(ResponseStream, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress))
                            {
                                _deflStream.CopyTo(_memStream);
                            };
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ResponseStream.CopyTo(_memStream);
                        }

                        _memStream.Position = 0;
                        using (StreamReader _reader = new StreamReader(_memStream, encoding))
                        {
                            Payload = _reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                        };
                    };
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Payload = string.Empty;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException exW)
    {
        if (exW.Response != null)
        {
            //Handle WebException
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception exS)
    {
        //Handle System.Exception
    }

    CookieJar = httpRequest.CookieContainer;
    return Payload;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this function did it perfect, just like you said it, at the third request I had got the menu I wanted. Thank you again

Comment: Well, I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: I am afraid I need your help again. I am trying to use your function to perform a POST request with parameters. I have set the httprequest.Method="POST" and used the StreamWriter to write the parameters but the request don't send the parameters. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Add the code you are using for posting to your question, some details on what format the server requires (e.g UrlEncoded, Json, UTF8 etc.) and the target (e.g. Post and Order, fill the fields of a Form etc.). If you are posting an order (for a book, for example) the required parameters are usually specified in some documentation and you are provided with an authetication token. In short, describe the context. (I'm working right now, I'll do what I can as soon as I have some time). (Also note that you should - by SO rules - post a new question. A moderator might disagree with this request).

Comment: OK, no problem, I will post a new question. Thank you again.

Comment: Allright. Maybe let me know when you do. I already know this context, so I can give some advice if someone answers first.

Comment: Ok, here is the link for my [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49375109/7706449)