# C# HttpWebRequest POST not sending parameters

Tags: c#, post, parameters

I am trying to perform a POST request with parameters using the next code. I'm using a local php script to receive the parameters, but when I perform the request the php script is not receiving the parameters sent form my C# function; it say

> Notice: Undefined index: detalle.
>
> Notice: Undefined index: method:paginar
>
> Notice: Undefined index: f_num_pagina

Function:

```
public async Task<string> GetHttpStream(Uri HtmlPage, string method, byte[] postData)
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest;
        string Payload = string.Empty;
        httpRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(HtmlPage);
        try
        {
            httpRequest.CookieContainer = CookieJar;
            httpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            httpRequest.ConnectionGroupName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            httpRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            httpRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            httpRequest.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 30000;
            httpRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
            httpRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0";
            httpRequest.Accept = "ext/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            httpRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
            httpRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate;q=0.8");
            httpRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache");
            httpRequest.Method = method;
            if (method == "POST")
            {
                httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                httpRequest.ContentLength = postData.Length;
                using (var stream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
                }
            }
            using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                Stream ResponseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();

                if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //ResponseStream.Position = 0;
                        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(httpResponse.CharacterSet);

                        using (MemoryStream _memStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            if (httpResponse.ContentEncoding.Contains("gzip"))
                            {
                                using (GZipStream _gzipStream = new GZipStream(ResponseStream, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress))
                                {
                                    _gzipStream.CopyTo(_memStream);
                                };
                            }
                            else if (httpResponse.ContentEncoding.Contains("deflate"))
                            {
                                using (DeflateStream _deflStream = new DeflateStream(ResponseStream, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress))
                                {
                                    _deflStream.CopyTo(_memStream);
                                };
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ResponseStream.CopyTo(_memStream);
                            }
                            _memStream.Position = 0;
                            using (StreamReader _reader = new StreamReader(_memStream, encoding))
                            {
                                Payload = _reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                            };
                        };
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
                        Payload = string.Empty;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException exW)
        {
            if (exW.Response != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exW.Message, "Error");
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception exS)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exS.Message, "Error");
        }
        CookieJar = httpRequest.CookieContainer;
        return Payload;
    }
```

Calling function:

```
var postData = "detalle=1&method:paginar=2&f_num_pagina=2";
byte[] parameters= Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
string HtmlPage = await GetHttpStream(url, "POST", parameters);
```

Comment: did you check the c# variables are fill up with data?

Comment: I already put a breakpoint and inspected the variables and everything it's fine

Comment: mostly this kind of errors coming because uninitialized variables. It can be either in c# code or in php script.

Comment: Not directly related with the error, but, since you have an async method, you should use the `await` operator: `await httpRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync()` and `httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)await httpRequest.GetResponseAsync()`. You should post the Uri of the page (if possible), to test the results of your POST. The error you receive seems related to the parameter you are passing: they server/script is rejecting them as "undefined". How did you get to know what parameters to post and the meaning of their values? Is there a way to verify them?

Comment: I had performed a new test and the "detalle" value is being receiving without problems, but the rest two values are not being received. The problems seems to be in postData string

Comment: Try to UrlEncode your parameters: `WebUtility.UrlEncode(postdata)` and then convert it in a byte array (as you are already doing).

Comment: I forgot to mention that, in this kind of Posts, `AllowAutoRedirect` should be set to `false`. The redirection after the query should be followed manually, testing the `Location` Header of the response. The StatusCode may be set to `302` (Found). Sometimes `303` (Redirected). The `Referer` Header of the `WebRequest`, set to the original request address.

Comment: Please add a minimal, complete and verifiable example to the question. See the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) StackOverflow Help Center page.

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev this is the (link)[https://sede.educacion.gob.es/publiventa/inicio.action] of the page which I need tu get the content. The POST request is for using the pagination system from my application.

Comment: @Jimi I tryied both of your recomendations but It's not working. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for helping and excuse me, but I just was confused, I was sending request to /inicio.action but the action of the pagination form was /busqueda.action.